# What is the difference between declarative and imperative programming in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, imperative-programming, declarative-programming

Recently, I was searching for a way to enhance navigating between screens in my Flutter apps. and I found new programming concepts for me (**declarative** and **imperative** programming). I need to know more about the **declarative** and **imperative** paradigms with an example in Flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Declarative Routing** means your app can open link with the right screen like browser,
you don't need to care about low level implementation as you do it with **imperative routing** in which you use Navigator functions like push() and pop(),

So declarative routing helps you develop higher level routing easily in your APP without caring its low level implementation.

**Go_Router** package is an example of declarative routing

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I also found some useful links that helped me:
- https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/flutter-for/declarative
- https://medium.com/flutter/learning-flutters-new-navigation-and-routing-system-7c9068155ade