# Flutter Web Navigation w/ Static Menu Bar?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm coming from Flutter Mobile and have been asked to build a flutter web app. I'm literally stuck on what feels like something that should be easy to do and I cannot for the life of me find any tutorial that is helpful.

The long and short is how can I build a flutter web app with a static navigation bar and only load pages into the "content" portion of the app.

I've been looking at this tutorial: https://dariadobszai.medium.com/interactive-navigation-items-in-flutter-web-7fccc5975779 however I can't figure out how to get it working with [GoRouter](https://pub.dev/packages/go_router). The pages also load a bit clunky.

Almost all the tutorials I can find are about resizing for web/mobile and do not get into any actual navigation. The responsiveness is nice, but how the heck do I navigate between pages with a static menu bar for a nice user experience?

Ideally the solution will utilize this menu (or one like it): https://pub.dev/packages/easy_sidemenu and https://pub.dev/packages/go_router.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest start researching about Go router first not how to implement a static menu navigation bar, since Go router uses declarative routing which changes completely how navigation should be handled.
I recommend this [repo](https://github.com/bizz84/nested_navigation_examples/tree/main/examples/gorouter) since it has different examples to use Go router, though be careful some examples may be deprecated.

Comment: Hi Iaila! Thanks for the reply. I don't know that this is the answer I'm really looking for, but you definitely got me thinking about this project differently, so thank you for that!

Thank you for the repo link. I also came across this SO post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74054426/what-is-the-difference-between-declarative-and-imperative-programming-in-flutter , which also has some helpful links for this. I'll go ahead and mark your post as the answer for now.

Answer (score 0):

Transitioning from Flutter Mobile to Flutter Web can indeed present some challenges, especially when it comes to navigation.

As indicated by @laila-nabil you should first start by researching about GoRouter package and understanding the basics. It's essential to understand the difference between **declarative navigation and imperative navigation**, since for Web you shall use declarative navigation, which involves defining the navigation structure in advance.

I would recommend using [path URLs strategy](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/navigation/url-strategies#configuring-the-url-strategy), as it helps in creating meaningful and shareable URLs. One crucial consideration for Flutter Web is that users can navigate both through in-app navigation and by manually entering URLs in the address bar. You should implement [redirection](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Redirection-topic.html) in your GoRouter configuration which ensures that users land on the correct page even when entering URLs directly.

Finally, you could use `ShellRoute` in your GoRouter to [define the "root widget"](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/go_router/ShellRoute-class.html) of your application which would include the **static menu bar** and the different child pages will be the routes of this ShellRoute.

If you then want to add more flexible navigation while also updating the URL you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77009974/21188902).